# Android : Not getting deeplink inside onAppOpenAttribution() method of AppsFlyer

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

We are using AppsFlyer to create deferred deeplink to redirect to our app, but we are getting the first 29-30 character of deeplink rather than complete deeplink which we have mentioned in the portal.

Any suggestions?

How to use AppsFlyer to use deferred deeplink?

We are passing below mentioned information in AppsFlyer Portal :[image]

Deeplink which is getting used :
**abcapp://grid?url=https://catalog.abcapp.com/v1/g/electronics-store/_the-mobile-store**

In app we are getting :

```
@Override
public void onAppOpenAttribution(Map<String, String> map) 
{
    String a = map.get("link");
}
```

the value of a we are getting is **abcapp://grid?url=https**

Answer (score 2):

For deferred deeplinks (first launch deeplinks) with AppsFlyer you should use the following method:

```
 @Override
    public void onInstallConversionDataLoaded(Map<String, String> conversionData) {
        for (String attrName : conversionData.keySet()) {
            Log.d(AppsFlyerLib.LOG_TAG, "attribute: " + attrName + " = " + 
            conversionData.get(attrName));
        }
    }
```

Additional information on deferred deeplinks and conversion data is available [here](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032176-Accessing-AppsFlyer-Attribution-Conversion-Data-from-the-SDK-Deferred-Deeplinking-)

*onAppOpenAttribution()* is used to receive data from "regular" deeplinks.

Regardless, if you are testing by explicitly clicking the deeplink / calling the deeplink from `adb` (and not a OneLink which contains the deeplink) you should encode your URL, for the URL in you example it should look like this:

```
abcapp%3A%2F%2Fgrid%3Furl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fcatalog.abcapp.com%2Fv1%2Fg%2Felectronics-store%2F_the-mobile-store
```

(The AppsFlyer Dashboard encodes automatically when you create a OneLink)

If you require additional assistance, you can contact the support team at [support@appsflyer.com](http://mailt://support@appsflyer.com) and we would happily assist.